# javascript: split multidimension array upon duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am stuck with splitting an array in multiple parts, based on pairs and duplicates.

I have this array :

```
var array = [[24, 17],[45, 17],[17, 24],[38, 31],[31, 38],[17, 45]];
```

and i need to split it to obtain this :

```
var array = [[24,17,45],[38,31]];
```

Does someone have any idea of the right way to do it ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: can you explain how you got your input and how you generated your output? there's no clear correlation.

Comment: I have a threejs scene, and the input is what i got when i list the ids of meshes that are colliding each other. The input array is what i obtain after iterating the scene.
In this example, 24 collides 17, 17 collides 24, 45 collides 17, 17 collides 45, 38 collides 31, and 31 collides 38.
Unfortunately, the output is not generated, because this is what i need to obtain,in order to know how many 'groups of colliding meshes' i have on the stage.

Comment: btw it would be helpful for me in the future to know why my question had been scored -1 !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the power of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and check if the one of the value is already in one set. If not create a new result set with a new set.

```js
var array = [[24, 17], [45, 17], [17, 24], [38, 31], [31, 38], [17, 45]],
    result = array
        .reduce((r, a) => {
            var s = r.find(s => a.some(Set.prototype.has, s));
            if (s) {
                a.forEach(v => s.add(v));
            } else {
                r.push(new Set(a));
            }
            return r;
        }, [])
        .map(s => Array.from(s));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina Scholz you saved my day, your solution is working great, than you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), and then [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the array. Using a helper [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), add a new sub array when a duplicate is detected. Afterwards, filter out the empty arrays:

```js
const array = [[24, 17],[45, 17],[17, 24],[38, 31],[31, 38],[17, 45]];

const helperSet = new Set();
const result = [].concat(...array)
  .reduce((r, n) => {
    !r[r.length - 1] && r.push([]);
    
    if(!helperSet.has(n)) {
      r[r.length - 1].push(n)
      helperSet.add(n);
    } else {
      r.push([]);
    };
  
    return r;
  }, [])
  .filter(({ length }) => length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hashtable that maps a certain mesh to a collision, so you can group them easily:

```js
const array = [[24, 17],[45, 17],[17, 24],[38, 31],[31, 38],[17, 45]];

const result = [], hash = {};

 for(const [a, b] of array) {
  let group = hash[a] || hash[b] || (arr => (result.push(arr), hash[a] = hash[b] = arr))([]);
  if(!group.includes(a)) group.push(a);
  if(!group.includes(b)) group.push(b);
}

console.log(result);
```